# Post to Facebook group via graph api c#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post to a facebook group via the graph api in c#.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group/feed

According to the api I can post a message as well as a link to a url, here is my code to try and do this:

```
Uri result;
bool X = Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out result)
if(X){
  // POST to group FB
  dynamic fbInfo = fb.Post("/v2.2/" + "groupID" + "/feed", new
  {
       message = websiteDesc,
       link = url
  });
  var fbInfoJson = fbInfo.ToString();
}
```

First i check that the url is absolute and if so proceed to post to the facebook group. 
so far this code does post to the group but only the message and not the link.

How can I get it to post the link?

Also the api says that I can include a photo to the post but it must be a string, can i assume this is the url of the image?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure, but the docs say "Either link or message must be supplied" so maybe you can only post a message OR a link. Definitely worth to try. It must be an absolute URL, of course. Same goes for the picture.

Posting in a group is pretty hard nowadays anyway, since you would need `user_groups` and `publish_actions` for that - and you will not get `user_groups` approved so you can´t use it for a public App. It will only work for users with a role in the App (Admin, Developer, Tester).

Comment: This is for a private group and members will all be testers (small group). 
If I only send the link not the message I recieve this error: {"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."}